# Investigation for a smooth and fast UI, doubts using Svelte 3

Tags: javascript, navigation, settimeout, requestanimationframe, svelte

## Issue

I'm using Svelte 3 and the amazing `svelte-spa-router` (https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router)!

**The question is not intended for exclusive use with this router.**

Many projects has heavy pages with heavy scripts.

I need a smooth and fast UI with immediate feedback when I change page.

## One possible solution

As you can read here: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2979 about a year ago I asked for something similar to the authors of Svelte.

A few hours ago @jacwright suggested using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` (https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2979#issuecomment-587979989).

```js
export async function awaitFrames (count = 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    await new Promise(requestAnimationFrame)
  }
}
```

```
onMount(async () => {
  await awaitFrames(2);
  mySlowFunction(10);
  loaded = true;
});
```

## Question time

I still don't know if this is the best solution for the problem.

- **Is there anything better that can be done?**
- **Is `requestAnimationFrame` the best tool to address this?**

## Reproduction

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/investigation-for-a-fluid-ui-bhknp.

As you can see if you click on:

1. **Light page**:

   1. when you click it loads immediately!
2. **Hard page**:

   1. when you click the page freeze
   2. slow CPU intensive work goes on and
   3. only after that Svelte renders the page
3. **Hard page with rAF**:

   1. when you click the page loads immediately
   2. after that the CPU intensive work begins
   3. after that CPU work the `loaded` var is set to `true`

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. If you run your heavy function synchronously and onMount, then of course, it will block the UI. But there's either no need to do that (use promises) or the user will have to accept that he has to wait for results.

Comment: Also if I use promises the problem is there.

Comment: Both your examples, that show the bad user experience, run the 'slow function' synchronously inside the onMount function. That is a no-go. Whatever you implement on the lifecycle methods has to return almost immediately. You can trigger heavy work but don't (a)wait for the results.

Comment: Can you show me an example using that codesandbox REPL (https://codesandbox.io/s/investigation-for-a-fluid-ui-bhknp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a svelte problem, it is a common problem for all web applications: javascript is single-threaded, when you stress the client with a long-running process, then the user can't use the interface. And, yes, this also holds true when we wrap the long running task in a promise. Should be the same with react or vue and it should also be the same problem when you serve the pages and also send the script to the client.

So, either avoid long running tasks on the browser or split them in smaller chunks so that the user can still interact with the UI - or use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

And of course, you can still use a SPA based on svelte (or react or vue) and call API on the backend that does the calculation.

Comment: If I cannot use WW, split in chunks and others methods you list but I need an immediate feedback and only then my user can wait (ONLY THEN, I REPEAT) only then the immediate page change, do you think using requestAnimationFrame is a good way? This is my question about.

Comment: I think maybe a promise approach can save me from using `requestAnimationFrame`. But how in that REPL? Can you help me?